# Access current node's key/name in PyYAML

Tags: python, pyyaml

I'm using custom YAML tags to deserialize YAML files into Python objects. Like this:

```
MyList:
  Object1: !MyObject
    value1: Test
    value2: 1.0
```

By means of a `class_method` `from_yaml` I call the `MyObject` `__init__` method and send it all the fields that `loader.construct_mapping` provides.

```
@classmethod
def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
  fields = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep = True)
  return cls(**fields)
```

All the configured fields are that way handed to the `__init__` method of `MyObject`. All, but one: the actual name of the described `MyObject` instance, i.e. the string `Object1`.

How do I get the instance's name in order to do something like so that `name == "Object1"`

```
def __init__(self, name, **fields):
  self.name = name
  for attr in fields:
    val = fields[attr]
    setattr(self, attr, val)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have mapping in your YAML with a key `Object1` and a value that is a tagged mapping with tag `!MyObject`. For YAML that key is not the name of the instance, it is just a key in mapping, whose value happens to be a tagged mapping.

When constructing that tagged mapping **that key is not available** as it is not part of your object. The parser of course already has that key `Object1` constructed somewhere as a node, when it starts parsing your object, but you cannot access that without heavily changing the parser. And if you do that, things would likely break if your YAML looked like:

```
MyList:
  - !MyObject
    value1: Test
    value2: 1.0
```

where there is no such key.

IMO you should change your YAML to look like:

```
MyList: !MyObject
  Object1:
    value1: Test
    value2: 1.0
```

Or to the following, that is easier to load:

```
MyList:
  - !MyObject
    name: Object1
    value1: Test
    value2: 1.0
```

If you cannot change your YAML, your best option is to write a (recursive) tree-walker that updates your objects after your call to `safe_load()`.

You should also consider writing `from_yaml` as a generator. As it is now it will break as soon as your `!MyObject` gets more complicated values that might include self-references at some point in the future.